# Search max value and index inside Nested list

Tags: c#

I know I can get the max value and index from a simple list in this way

```
List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>()
                        {
                         new Employee{Age=15, name = "Tom"},
                         new Employee{Age=17, name = "Billy"},
                         new Employee{Age=25, name = "Sam"}
                        };

int maxvalue = emplist.Select(i => i.Age).Max();
int index = empList.FindIndex(t => t.Age == maxvalue);
```

But for a nested list

```
List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>()
                    {
                     new Employee{Age=15, name = "Tom", new List<project>
                     {
                        ID = 12, name = "Project A",
                        ID = 11, name = "Project B",
                        ID = 16, name = "Project C"
                     }},
                     new Employee{Age=17, name = "Billy",new List<project>
                     {
                        ID = 17, name = "Project D",
                        ID = 18, name = "Project E",
                        ID = 10, name = "Project F"
                     }},
                     new Employee{Age=25, name = "Sam",new List<project>
                     {
                        ID = 22, name = "Project X",
                        ID = 24, name = "Project Y",
                        ID = 19, name = "Project Z"
                     }}
                    };
```

I know how to get the max value of ID but have no idea how to get the two indexes of it.

```
int maxvalue = emplist.SelectMany(i => i.project).Select(a => a.ID).Max();
```

The max value is 24.
I want to get the two indexes as well ( Index 2 of employee and Index 1 of project)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select max element from a list of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594874/select-max-element-from-a-list-of)

Comment: You should not be re-posting your question if you don't get an answer suitable for you.  Instead edit your existing question to further clarify what it is that you want, and why the information provided doesn't solve your problem.  If your question is put on hold, after addressing the reason it was put on hold, it can be re-opened.

Comment: No, they are not the same question. It is about finding two indexes of the max valuein a nested list.I dont even know what I am asking when I read my old question. Thus, the answers provided could not solve my real problem.

Comment: @Servy his existing question get closed

Comment: @WiiMaxx I know it did, which is why I specifically addressed the fact that it was closed in my comment to him.  When you question is closed you need to fix it, not re-ask it.

Comment: @IsoletChan Which is what your previous question is, it's just not phrased as well as this one.  You should be editing your previous question, not asking a new one.

Comment: @Servy: IMO, the question that is apparently duplicated by his previous question doesn't really answer the main point here: Getting the indexes. It just shows how to get the *instance* but not the index of it inside the enumerable. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: None of the answers can help me find both the indexes because I explained badly.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Correct, in his previous question he phrased it poorly, and as a result it was incorrectly closed as a duplicate of a question that's not really a duplicate, because he was mis-understood.  He should edit his question, clarify his meaning, and then it can be re-opened.

Comment: @IsoletChan Yes, and so I've told you several times now, when that happens you should edit your question to clarify what you meant, not ask a new question.

Comment: I followed the guide : please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question.

Comment: @IsoletChan Yes, and you should have done the former in this case, since the issue was that you were mis-understood, not that you asked the wrong question.

Comment: @Servy: I don't agree. Extensively editing the old question makes the existing answers obsolete. And the comments, too. It is simpler and less confusing for everybody involved to just leave the old one closed and to answer this question.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The answers were incorrect, from the start.  They were never correct; they are not correct now.  I see no comments that would be made obsolete by him fixing his question.

Comment: @Servy: So, what do you suggest? Should the mod that re-opens the question delete the old answers, too? I think you are reading the rule too literal here.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth They are incorrect answers to the question.  As with any other incorrect answer on any other question, they can be downvoted.  Since they are an attempt to answer the question, they should not be deleted by a mod.

Comment: @Servy: Not a comparable scenario. However, as most of our discussions, this one will never reach a conclusion, so I am ending it now.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth How is it not comparable?  The people that posted the answer misunderstood the question.  It's an understandable mistake to make, as the question wasn't very clear, but they misunderstood it nonetheless, and posted an incorrect answer as a result of that misunderstanding.  I would have preferred it to be closed as "unclear".

Comment: @Servy: After the edit of the question, those answers will be incorrect answers *to a different question*. Oh and, as far as I can see, Tim's answer was correct. But after the edit, it still will be an answer to a different question.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth They are *already* answers to a different question, one that was never asked.  They misunderstood the question that is currently there, and as of right now, with no edits, they are already wrong.  This is the problem with attempting to answer a very unclear question, and why it's better to close them as "unclear" until they are clarified.

Comment: I am a new member and I dont know the rules well. Sorry for all my mistakes. I tried to edit the old question but I cant(Duplicate topic ). I flagged the old question for the moderator to delete that unclear question.

Comment: @IsoletChan: As you can see from this extensive discussion, even long-time members don't always agree on how to interpret the rules, so don't worry. Just try to conform to the rules as best as you can.

Comment: @IsoletChan It doesn't bother me too much that you were unsure what to do.  What does bother me is that after suggesting that you edit the question to make your intentions clear, you never did.  The fact that the question is on hold does *not* prevent you from editing it.  You should have edited the question to clarify why the proposed duplicate doesn't answer your question, you should have commented on the existing answers explaining why they don't help you.  The biggest issue here is that nobody had any way of knowing that you didn't get your answer on the last question.

Comment: I cant edit it  because I opened this question. The same topic makes the system considered I am spamming. I flagged the old one for the moderator to delete and intend to keep this question as it it well answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overload of `Select` which projects also the index to create an anonymous type:

```
var maxItem = emplist
   .Select((emp, index) => new 
    { 
        maxProject = emp.project
            .Select((proj, pIndex) => new{ proj, pIndex })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.proj.ID)
            .First(),
        emp, index 
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.maxProject.proj.ID)
    .First();
Console.Write("Max-Value:{0} Emp-Index:{1} Project-Index:{2}"
    , maxItem.maxProject.proj.ID
    , maxItem.index 
    , maxItem.maxProject.pIndex);
```

(disclaimer: untested, presumes that all employees have a non-empty `List<Employee> project`)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following Linq

```
var result =  emplist.Select((x,i) => new { index = i, item = x})
                     .SelectMany(x => x.item.project.Select(
                          (a,i) => new { index = x.index, subindex = i, id = a.ID}))
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.id )
                     .First();
```

- First index will be in `result.index` = 2
- Second index will be in `result.subindex` = 1
- ID will be in `result.id` = 24

Answer (score 1):

this would be do the same without odering your projectlist:

```
    var employee    = emplist.Aggregate((e1, e2) => (e1.project.Max(p1 => p1.ID) > e2.project.Max(p2 => p2.ID)) ? e1 : e2);
    var employeeidx = emplist.IndexOf(employee);
    var project     = employee.project.Aggregate((p1, p2) => (p1.ID > p2.ID) ? p1 : p2);
    var projectidx  = employee.project.IndexOf(project);
    var value       = project.ID;
```